# AWS Bucket or CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm wrinting a PHP API that serves mobile apps, hosted in the AWS. This app is image based, like Instagram. All the images are uploaded in a AWS Bucket and requested using a GET url, for example `http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image-name.extension`. My question is: what is the best way to serve those images? With AWS Bucket or CloudFront?

Thanks!

Comment: Cloudfront, no doubts. Cloudfront pick your S3 bucket and replicate in servers across the world. This makes your distribution faster that if you only use S3.

Comment: @jherran So, I should keep my S3 and add a CloudFront as CDN?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Comment: @jherran Add your comment as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudfront, no doubts. Cloudfront pick your S3 bucket and replicate in servers across the world. This makes your distribution faster that if you only use S3.

Comment: *"...replicate in servers across the world..."* Not exactly.  Cloudfront is a pull-through cache with independent globally-distributed nodes.  There is no active replication of content.  Still, it's a logical choice for the fastest global response times, at least on popular downloads.